# Error:- This field must be indexed to enforce unique values

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to create a field in sharepoint list with unique values.

```
  string fieldSchema = "<Field Type='" + field.FieldTypeKind + "' Indexed='" + indexing + "' DisplayName='" + field.Title + "' Name='" + field.InternalName + "' EnforceUniqueValues='" + field.EnforceUniqueValues + "' Hidden='" + field.Hidden + "' Required='" + field.Required + "'><Default>'" + field.DefaultValue + "'</Default></Field>";

                                targetcollField.AddFieldAsXml(fieldSchema, true, AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
                                targetContext.Load(targetcollField);
                                srcFieldCollections.Add(field);
```

But it throws exception "This field must be indexed to enforce unique values."

I have also tried

```
 if (field.EnforceUniqueValues == true)
                                    {
                                        field.Indexed = true;
                                        field.EnforceUniqueValues = true;
                                        field.Update();
                                        targetContext.ExecuteQuery();
                                    }
```

But still it throws same error.

Answer (score 2):

The only possible reason for your error is you are trying to index the field which is not available to indexed.

Error Cases - Exceptions

There are two error cases associated with using the `EnforceUniqueValues` property to enforce uniqueness:

`EnforceUniqueValues = true` is set on a non-indexed field.

> Throws an exception object (SPException) with a message reading "The
>   field must first be indexed to enforce unique values.

`EnforceUniqueValues = true` is set on a list that has existing duplicate values.

> Throws an exception object (SPException) with a message reading "This
>   field contains duplicate values. Remove all duplicate values and try
>   the operations again.

**Unsupported Column Types to be indexed**

- Multiple lines of text
- Hyperlink/Picture
- Custom Field Types
- Calculated Field
- Boolean (yes/no)
- UI version
- Checked out to
- Content type ID

You can get detail [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536168(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: I am doing it for single line text column